# EF Core 5: Linq query works locally, but fails online (Azure)

Tags: asp.net, azure, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having issues with a Linq query that can't be translated, but before I go into detail on the code, I have a general question.

My query works if I test my Web Api locally with IIS, but when I publish it to Azure, it gives me an error, saying that it can't be translated.

So my question is, what could be the reason for this? How is it possible, that it produces different results after publish? It's really annoying to make something work only to find out later that it doesn't work when published. This way I will have to publish all of the time to make sure that it actually works.

For the actual problem, my query looks like this:

```
    var innerJoinQuery =
    from user in _context.Users
    join historyentry in _context.ResourceHistory on user.UserId equals historyentry.UserId
    join resource in _context.UserResource on historyentry.UserId equals resource.UserId
    join userProfile in _context.UserProfiles on resource.UserId equals userProfile.UserId
    where historyentry.ShortName.Equals(shortName)
                    && historyentry.CreatedUtc > startUtc 
                    && historyentry.CreatedUtc < endUtc
    select new BoardEntry()
    {
        UserId = user.UserId,
        ResourceShortName = resource.ShortName,
        ResourceDisplayName = resource.DisplayName,
        UserDisplayName = userProfile.DisplayName,
        Amount = historyentry.Amount
    };
```

This is the error I get:

> The LINQ expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u2.UserId ORDER BY
> u2.UserId ASC, r0.HistoryEntryId ASC, u3.ResourceId ASC, u4.ProfileId
> ASC)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that
> can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
> inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'.

Setup:

EF Core 5.0.17

MariaDB 10.3

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.4

Comment: Which error? Which query? Show call stack.

Comment: Are you using the Inmemory provider locally by any chance?

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick answers, I know that I don't give a lot of information on my actual problem, but I don't understand why this can be happening generally... @ErikEJ I'm sorry to say that I don't know what that is, but if that is something that my asp project set up by default, it could very well be.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I will edit my answer to show the query, maybe the problem is obvious ^^

Comment: Specify versions of databases. And from your query I do not see why EF Core requires `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are right, my MariaDB version on Azure is 10.3 and my local MariaDB version is 10.11... that might be the problem...

Comment: Window functions are introduced from version 10.2.0. Which EF Core provider do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.17

Comment: `Pomelo` or official Oracle provider? And your question title do not equal to specified version. I'm almost tired. Update question with all details.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I updated my question. Sorry for my bad thread, I will be more explicit in the future and thanks so much for helping me again!

Comment: The why, is because of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: How it works locally and fails on Azure, that's a good question

Comment: How Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.4 works with EF Core 3.1? It is targeted to EF Core (>= 5.0.10 && < 6.0.0)

Comment: "It's really annoying to make something work only to find out later that it doesn't work when published" - you must be new here! Welcome to software development! By the way, that's not a bug. It's a feature called "job security"

Comment: Anyway, error that you have shown introduced in EF Core 5.0 (not sure). `builder.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)` - set appropriate server version.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I can't believe it, but you managed to be my hero two days in a row. I had Server Version set to auto detect and now I set it to "new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 0)" and the problem seems to be solved. Really I can't thank you enough! Would you write your comment as a short answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv and I was obviously already tired yesterday, I'm using EF Core 5.0.17. Maybe I was confused by .Net Core 3.1, I don't know, sorry!

Comment: @ManuBera, title of your question starts with EF Core 3.1. Evil in small details.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This is embarrassing xD It seems that I wasn't tired, I was just stupid. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staring from EF Core 5.0 for subqueries which has row count limitation (`Take(1)`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc.) instead of `CROSSS/OUTER APLLY`, LINQ Translator generates join to query with Window function `ROW_NUMBER`. Not all versions of MariaDB supports Window functions and probably `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` provider has bug in server version autodetection for MariaDB, so try to specify version explicitly:

```cs
builder.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion);
```

Comment: Again, I can't thank you enough. You sir are a scholar and a gentleman :)